# How to create a new menu item with information from database php and sessions

Tags: php, mysql, html, mysqli

Sorry if this has been asked already before, but I tried looking for the answer and couldn't find it.

I am creating a website where a user submits information on their child such as age, school, skill level, etc. when registering.

Once they have completed registering their information and child information they can sign in and go to their dashboard.

I have a menu item that is called "dancers" and the sub menu item should be the dancer/child name that was entered when they registered. another menu item that is also there is "add new dancer".

So what I am trying to do is  when they register, upon signing in they should already have the dancer in the dropdown menu for "dancers". which would have been retrieved from the database.

And every time they add a new dancer a new submenu item of that dancer's name should appear.

here is my html menu code:

```
<div class="row subnav">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
       <ul>
        <li class="li-spacing"><a href="parentdashboard.php">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown li-spacing">
           <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dancers<b class="caret"></b></a>
           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Name</a></li>
            <li class="divider"><hr></li>
            <li><a href="#">Name</a></li>
            <li class="divider"><hr></li>
            <li><a href="#">Add New</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
        <li class="dropdown li-spacing">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Report Cards <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">View all</a></li>
            <li class="divider"><hr></li>
            <li><a href="#">Add New</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="li-spacing"><a href="#">History</a></li>
        <li class="li-spacing"><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li class="li-spacing"><a href="#">Fun</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>       
</div>
```

I am very new to php, and really need some direction in where to start with this.

any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome in stackoverflow Please Read more about PHP,mysql,html and start from small examples then try this.

Comment: Where is the code to read something from the database to populate the select?

Comment: You can start learning from w3schools. It will be simple and easy. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much research and working on other pages on my website I have finally found a solution that worked perfect for me.

```
<div class="row subnav">
<div class="col-sm-12">
   <ul>
    <li class="li-spacing"><a href="parentdashboard.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown li-spacing">
       <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dancers<b class="caret"></b></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <?php
        $dancers = "SELECT `dancer_name` FROM `dancers` WHERE name = '$name'";
        $dres = mysqli_query($con,$dancers); 
        if($res==FALSE){
        die('there was an error running query [' . $con->error . ']');
        }
        while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($dres)){
            echo '
                <li><a href="dancerProfile.php">'.$data["dancer_name"].'</a></li>
                <li class="divider"><hr></li>
                ';
                }
               ?>
       </ul>
     </li>
  </ul>
```